# Apache rewrites, how do I extract a word and a number from a URL and pass them into php?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Say I have `http://www.domain.com/whatever-with-hyphens-6.shml`

And I want to pass `whatever-with-hyphens` and `6` to my php script, how would I achieve this?

`/php/catpages.php?cat=$1&page=$2`

It would be the last rule and case insensitive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.+)-([0-9]+)\.shml /php/catpages.php?cat=$1&page=$2  [L,NC]
```

This should rewrite `http://www.domain.com/whatever-with-hyphens-6.shml` to `/php/catpages.php?cat=whatever-with-hyphens&page=6`

Comment: Jules: for me it's +1, not -1 just tested it and it works. Could you explain what is "that didn't work", maybe you have some other rules conflicting, what do you observe?

Comment: Sorry, that "R" shouldn't have been in the brackets. But it shouldn't have had any effect on it not working for you, it just caused the browser to redirect instead of an internal redirect.

Answer (score -1):

I would not pass them to your php script as get variables.
Have your php controller script parse the requested page name itself.

Instead of /php/catepages.php?cat=$1&page=$2 as your redirect destination, have

/php/controller.php as your rewriterule destination.

Then you can use split or whatever on the requested URI and leave $_GET out of it all together.

Comment: I'm migrating a site, need to do this.

Comment: Jon - does that work if existing get variables are sent? Does mod_rewrite append existing get variables to the rewrite with get variables properly? I honestly don't know, but that's a concern for me anyway.

Comment: Yes it does work, but its on a windows server using ISAPI rewrites.